# ClearCase: Find files having exactly one specific label for one directory

Tags: for-loop, directory, label

i want search list of file with same label for one directory not for all file with same label in different directory
now i m using 
cleartool find /some/dir  -element "{lbtype_sub(S_CFTY720D2301_CSR)}" -print

Answer (score 0):

If your question is, "How do I search for elements in the /some/dir directory matching the query but prevent 'cleartool find' from descending into subdirectories?", look at the '–nr/ecurse' flag:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm